# PubSub: Where are Libraries org.ros.android.*

Tags: ros, external-libraries, libraries, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where in the Project can i find the imported Libraries

```
org.ros.android.* e.g. *MessageCallable
```

Haven t found them in external libraries.
There are (in rosjava-0.1.6.jar) org.ros.master,org.ros.node,...
But i have no clue where in my android_core project to fin org.ros.android.*

Thanks

---

For Installation i followed the [Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment)

---

can t find the sources in android studio - android_core (packages view or project view) and also not in my directories

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188782/pubsub:-where-are-libraries-org.ros.android.*/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your IDE can properly index the ros java and android projects, you should be able to follow the imports to their source (or perhaps only the interface, if you've installed a binary dist).

If you've installed from source, you should find the sources for those classes in your catkin workspace.

If all else fails: you can find the sources in the appropriate branches of the [android_core](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core) project in the [rosjava](https://github.com/rosjava) GitHub organisation. See [android_core/hydro](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/hydro) for the Hydro branch.

PS: there is quite some documentation on (part of) the ROS Android libraries. See fi: [android_core 0.1.0 documentation](http://rosjava.github.io/android_core/latest/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0